# How to programmatically link Field in Enterprise Portal AX 2009 to open a specifical File

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm a new beginner in Microsoft AX. I have a problem in AX 2009. I create a Table ImportFile with 2 Fields,("FileName-->Typ:String",  "FileDocuValue-->Typ:Container"). When the User import a CSV-File it will be save in the Table ImportFile. 
Now in EP I Just show in My GridView a Column FileName and I want that FileName be a Link so that when I click in one one these Names that it Open the Corresponding CSV-File in Excel.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following approach:

1. You can use a standard asp LinkButton control to display a link. When the link has been clicked,
2. Create a temporary CSV file from the data in your ImportFile table.
3. Create a URL to the generated CSV file (you can use the [WebLink.url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/weblink.url.aspx) method).
4. Open the generated URL.

When I was working on a similar task (generate and download PDF) I also had to modify some standard classes such as WebSession and EPDocuGetWebLet.

Comment: Thx for your answer but i just have a Problem. I need to do all of this implementation in AOT. How can I realise a asp LinkButton in AOT?

Comment: How exactly are you showing your GridView in Enterprise Portal - haven't you implemented it by creating a web control in Visual Studio? Technicaly it's still in the AOT (Web → Web Files → Web Controls) but the changes have to be done in Visual Studio. You can't really get away from ASP .NET development if you have to develop something complex in EP.

Comment: all what i done is in AOT. if it was in Virtual S´tudio i shal l finish it already.. The Problem is that the work has been shared. On the Server we don't have Visual Studio installed just the prerequisite for MS SQL.

Comment: "Now in EP i Just show in My GridView a Column FileName" - please clarify where exactly in AOT you made this change.